# Checar valores de instâncias de uma classe em php

Tags: php

Estou fazendo um trabalho pra escola. Acontece o professor, em uma das questões, foi solicitado o seguinte:

Uma classe chamada `País`.
Um de seus atributos sendo o `código ISO` (sigla de 3 letras ex : BRA, USA, ARG, etc).

E um dos itens dessa questão era ver se algum dos objetos da classe tinha o mesmo código ISO de outro.

Eu realmente não tenho ideia de como fazer isso.

Comment: Já tem alguma parte do código feita ? Por que se sim,poste para podermos lhe ajudar melhor nesta questão.

Comment: Você já tem pelo menos a classe?

Answer (score 1):

Sugiro estudar mais profundamente orientação a objetos, o exemplo abaixo é algo muito superficial e pouco ensina.

Primeiro precisamos criar uma classe com o nome `pais`.

```
namespace lib

/**
 * Classe Pais
 * @package lib
 */
class Pais
{
    /**
     * @var string $iso;
     */
    private $iso;

    /**
     * @var string $nome;
     */
    private $nome;

    /**
     * Atribui um valor a propriendade $iso
     * @param string $iso
     * @return lib\Pais
     */
    public function setIso($iso)
    {
        $this->iso = $iso

        $return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Retorna o valor da propriedade $iso
     * @return string
     */
    public funcion getIso()
    {
        return $this->iso;
    }

    /**
     * Atribui um valor a propriendade $nome
     * @param string $nome
     * @return lib\Pais
     */
    public function setNome($nome)
    {
        $this->nome = $nome

        $return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Retorna o valor da propriedade $nome
     * @return string
     */
    public funcion getNome()
    {
        return $this->nome;
    }
}
```

Primeiro atribuímos um `namespace` a classe. Namespace possibilita o agrupamento de classes visando evitar o conflito entre seus nomes, atuando como um encapsulador, ou seja, o seu funcionamento é equivalente ao de diretórios em sistemas operacionais, onde dois arquivos com o mesmo nome não podem existir em um único diretório, mas podem existir dois arquivos com o mesmo nome localizados em diretórios distintos.

Repare que a classe tem comentários e alguns começados com `@`. Esses comentários servem para padronizar e gerar documentação automática do seu código, utilizando ferramentas como o  [phpdoc](https://www.phpdoc.org/). Além da documentação, os comentários servem para auxiliar programadores que podem no futuro alterar o seu código, facilitando o entendimento do mesmo.

Veja que na classe nós definimos os métodos `get` e `set` para cada propriedade. Daí surge uma pergunta natural: por que criar métodos para acessar variáveis, se podemos acessá-las diretamente? - Por questão de segurança.

As variáveis `private` só podem ser acessadas de dentro da classe, ou seja, não podem ser acessadas fora do escopo da classe. Por exemplo, imagina que dentro do método `setIso` teríamos uma verificação se o código realmente existe; se a propriedade fosse `public`, poderíamos simplesmente setar qualquer valor a propriedade `iso` sem qualquer validação.

```
class Pais 
{
     // Propriedade pode ser acessada fora do escopo da classe Pais
     public $iso;
}

$pais = new Pais();
$pais->iso = 'QualquerValorParaIso';
```

Ao tentar acessar uma propriedade privada fora do escopo da classe, ocorrerá o seguinte erro:

```
class Pais 
{
     // Propriedade não pode ser acessada fora do escopo da classe Pais
     private $iso;
}

$pais = new Pais();
$pais->iso = 'QualquerValorParaIso';
```

> Error: Cannot access private property lib\Pais::$iso (500 Internal Server Error)

Esclarecido (espero eu) alguns conceitos, vamos criar agora um aquivo novo onde iremos fazer uso da classe `Pais`.

**teste.php**

```
use lib\Pais

$paisA = new Pais();
$paisA
    ->setName('Brasil')
    ->setIso('BRA')
;

$paisB = new Pais();
$paisB
    ->setName('Portugal')
    ->setIso('PRT')
;

$paisC = new Pais();
$paisC
    ->setName('Portugal')
    ->setIso('PRT')
;
```

O código acima gera 3 instâncias da classe `Pais`, ou seja, 3 objetos distintos e independentes uns dos outros, cada um com o seu escopo.

De uma maneira muito simples, podemos verificar se os valores definidos são iguais entre os objetos através do método `getIso`:

```
$isoA = $paisA->getIso(); //BRA
$isoB = $paisB->getIso(); //PRT
$isoC = $paisC->getIso(); //PRT

//output: não
echo 'Iso país A==B', $isoA==$isoB ? 'sim':'não';

//output: não
echo 'Iso país A==C', $isoA==$isoC ? 'sim':'não';

//output: sim
echo 'Iso país B==C', $isoB==$isoC ? 'sim':'não';
```

O método acima é ineficaz se existir um coleção de países, testar todas as combinações gerando uma linha para cada `if` ou até mesmo podemos não saber quantos itens existem na coleção, etc... usei o método acima apenas para demonstrar como criar uma instância da classe (que resulta em um objeto) e usar os respectivos métodos.

Cada caso é um caso e deve ser estudo de modo a ser implementado da melhor forma possível, mas para já o exemplo serve.

Comment: Eu realmente agradeço. Só um adendo: Eu já conheço o básico da orientação a objeto. Eu não que o que aconteceu que o site alterou meu texto kkkkkkkk. Eu havia dito que a unica parte que eu n tinha feito era a de checar as instâncias.

Comment: E novamente, obrigado, me ajudou bastante.

Answer (score 1):

Resolvi responder pois discordo um pouco da outra resposta, mas deixo claro que ela não deixa de estar certa também. Mas o ideal seria validar os dados de entradas e ter método para comparar dois países.

Segue o código, não vou estender muito pois o código já está intuitivo:

**Pais.php**:

```
<?php

/**
 * Class Pais
 * @author lvcs
 */
class Pais
{
    // Atributos da classe Pais
    private $iso;

    /**
     * Pais constructor, chama o set do ISO, para iniciar a classe já com um atributo,
     * caso não seja passado um parametro no construtor ele será nulo.
     * @param $iso
     */
    public function __construct($iso = null)
    {
        $this->setIso($iso);
    }

    /**
     * Compara dois, países e retorna se são iguais ou diferentes
     * @param $pais - país para comparar
     * @return bool - diferente ou igual
     * @throws Exception - retorna erros
     */
    public function equals($pais)
    {
        try
        {
            if(is_object($pais))
                return ($this->iso === $pais->iso);
            else
            {
                $pais = new Pais($pais);
                return $this->equals($pais);
            }

        }
        catch (Exception $e)
        {
            throw  new Exception("Parametro do método deve ser um objeto país ou um iso válido");
        }

    }

    /**
     * Retorna iso atual da classe
     * @return string
     */
    public function getIso()
    {
        return $this->iso;
    }

    /**
     * Rebece e valida código ISO para adicionar como atributo da classe
     * @param string $iso - novo falor a setar iso
     * @throws Exception - retorna erros
     */
    public function setIso($iso)
    {
        $length = mb_strlen($iso);
        if($length === 3)
            $this->iso = mb_strtoupper($iso);
        else if($length > 3)
            throw new Exception("ISO não pode ter mais de 3 letras.");
        else
            throw new Exception("ISO não pode ter menos de 3 letras.");
    }

}
```

`instanciando.php`:

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="pt">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
<?php

    // chama a classe
    require_once 'Pais.php';

    // Diz para o PHP que estamos usando strings UTF-8 até o final do script
    mb_internal_encoding('UTF-8');

    // Diz para o PHP que nós vamos enviar uma saída UTF-8 para o navegador
    mb_http_output('UTF-8');

    /**
     * Tenta criar países, caso tenha falha nisso então pega a mensagem de erro da classe
     * Saída: nenhuma, pois todos isos são válidos
     */
    try
    {
        $pais1 = new Pais("BRA");

        $pais2 = new Pais("EUA");

        $pais3 = new Pais("ITA");

        $pais4 = new Pais("EUA");
    }
    catch (Exception $e)
    {
        echo $e->getMessage();
    }

    /**
     * Tenta criar países, caso tenha falha nisso então pega a mensagem de erro da classe
     * Saída: 'ISO não pode ter menos de 3 letras.'
     */
    try
    {
        $pais5 = new Pais("BR");

        $pais6 = new Pais("IT");
    }
    catch (Exception $e)
    {
        echo $e->getMessage();
    }

    echo '<hr/><br/>';

    try
    {
        //compara país1 com país2 e joga o resultado de equals no método manipulaResultado. Saída: 'Países são diferentes'
        manipulaResultado( $pais1->equals($pais2) );
        echo '<br/>';

        //compara país1 com país2 e joga o resultado de equals no método manipulaResultado. Saída: 'Países são diferentes'
        manipulaResultado( $pais2->equals($pais3) );
        echo '<br/>';

        //compara país1 com país2 e joga o resultado de equals no método manipulaResultado. Saída: 'Países são iguais'
        manipulaResultado( $pais2->equals($pais4) );
        echo '<br/>';

        //compara país1 com país2 e joga o resultado de equals no método manipulaResultado. Saída: 'Países são iguais'
        manipulaResultado( $pais1->equals("BRA") );
        echo '<br/>';

        //compara país1 com país2 e joga o resultado de equals no método manipulaResultado. Saída: 'Parametro do método deve ser um objeto país ou um iso válido'
        manipulaResultado( $pais1->equals("BRASIL") );
        echo '<br/>';
    }
    catch (Exception $e)
    {
        echo $e->getMessage();
    }

    echo '<hr/><br/>';





/**
     * método para comparar se o resultado do método equals é true ou false, caso seja true então 
     * imprime que países são iguais, se não imprime que são diferentes
     * @param $resultado - resultado do método equals
     */
    function manipulaResultado($resultado)
    {
        echo ($resultado) ? "Países são iguais" : "Países são diferentes";
    }

?>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Discordo um pouco da sua resposta. Não deveria existir o método de comparação dentro do objeto, essa não é uma responsabilidade do objeto, acaba por perder um pouco a sua "identidade".

Comment: Não perde identidade, você pode vr que isso acontece com várias linguagens como a classe Sting do Java que tem esse mesmo método equals e assim por diante, se enquadra na orientação e engenharia. se toda classe tivesse apenas seus getters e setters então seria um caos, custo de manutenção seria altíssimo sem conta que o codigo não se enquadraria nada nos conceitos de engenharia de software. O ideal seria os getters, os setters e métodos de operações efetuada com aquele objeto.

Answer (score 0):

Ontem eu comecei a fazer e quando li a questão, vi que ele queria tudo dentro da própria classe. Então minha solução foi a seguinte (lembrando que pode haver erros de sintaxe, pois meu computador, por motivos místicos, é incapaz de instalar o servidor apache ou outro parecido).

```
class Pais{
private $nome;
private $iso;
private $pop;
private $lim;
private $dim


public function __construct($nome, $iso, $pop, $lim, $dim){
    $this -> nome = $nome;
    $this -> iso = $iso;
    $this -> pop = $pop;
    $this -> lim = explode(";", $lim);
    //referencia do explode php.net/pt_BR/function.explode.php
    $this -> dim = $dim;
}
public function setNome($nome){
     $this -> nome = $nome;
}
public function getNome(){
    return $this -> nome;
}
public function setISO($iso){
     $this -> iso = $iso;
}
public function getISO(){
    return $this -> iso;
}
public function setPop($pop){
     $this -> pop = $pop;
}
public function getPop(){
    return $this -> pop;
}
public function setLim($lim){
     $this -> lim = explode(";", $lim);
}
public function getLim(){
    return $this -> lim;
}
    public function setDim($dim){
     $this -> dim = $dim;
}
public function getDim(){
    return $this -> dim;
}

public function checaIgualdade($outroPais){
    if($this -> iso == $outroPais){
        echo "Mesmo País";
        unset ($outroPais);
        return 0;
    }
    if($this -> iso != $outroPais){
        echo "Paises diferentes";
        return 1;
    }
}
public function checaLimites($front){
    foreach ($this -> lim as $b => $a){
        if($a == $front){
            echo "Limítrofe.";
            $c = 1;
        }
        else{ 
        $c = 2;
        }
    }
    if($c != 1){
        echo "Não limitrofe.";
    }
}
```

Para explicar como instanciar um objeto:

```
$brasil = new Pais("Brasil", "BRA",  200000000, "Argentina, Paraguai", 8516000);
$alemanha = new Pais("Alemanha", "ALE", 80000000, "Polonia, Dinamarca", 357168);
```

A função que compara, funciona através do retorno de getIso:

```
$brasil -> checaIgualdade($alemanha -> getISO());
```

Acredito que esteja correto, mas n tenho como testar pra ter certeza.